# Calling grep after writing to file Python 2.6.4 os.system

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to read from `text.txt`, write certain lines to `temp.txt`, then using `os.system` call `grep` on `temp.txt`
After I run the program, `temp.txt` gets created and I can call the same `grep` command in terminal to get my desired results which makes me think this is an asynchronous problem

I'm using Python 2.6.4

```
import os

#opens new file to write to
temp = open("temp.txt", "w+")

boolStart = False
with open("text.txt", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        if("GREEN" in line):
            boolStart = True
        elif("YELLOW" in line):
            boolStart = False
        if(boolStart):
            temp.write(line)
            

os.system("grep -e 'Ace: ' -e 'Spade' {0}".format("temp.txt"))
```

I get nothing back from running `python script.py` even if I pipe to a new file

Question: Why aren't I able to call grep on a file I just wrote in the same program

For context this is `text.txt`

```
******************************
*************RED**************
******************************

Ace: John
Ace: Mike
Spade: Nick
Spade: Pete

******************************
***********GREEN**************
******************************

Ace: Emily
Ace: Anna
Spade: Krista
Spade: Maddie

******************************
*************YELLOW***********
******************************

Ace: Nicole
Ace: Scott
Ace: Zac
Ace: Phil
```

And this is `temp.txt` the file I'm trying to call `grep` on

```
***********GREEN**************
******************************

Ace: Emily
Ace: Anna
Spade: Krista
Spade: Maddie

******************************
```

Comment: Are you *forced* to use Python 2.6 for some reason, or have you just neglected to use something more up to date? At this point, there's little reason to be using anything older than Python 3.5 (and if you must use Python 2, you should be using 2.7).

Comment: Yes I have to use Python 2.6.4

Comment: The `grep` call is superfluous as such; even Python 2.6 understands `if 'Ace: ' in line or 'Spade: ' in line:`

Comment: I expected to be able to call grep and return the lines with 'Ace: ' and 'Spade:  ' instead of no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to `.close()` the file, which may leave buffered data which has yet to be written to disk.

However, there is no need to use `grep` or write the data to a temporary file.

```py
for line in text:
    # ...
    if BoolStart:
        if 'Ace:' in line or 'Spade:' in line:
            print(line)
```